# ImageView.SetImageResource method takes a lot of memory (40%)

Tags: android

I got app with `SQLite` database with saved names of drawables (strings). Multiple drawables are saved in `res/drawable` directory with their scalling sizes `drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi` etc. This device use mdpi. Their size is approx since 80 kB. Each time I call `update()` method I call `SetImageResource` method for the same `ImageView`and I only change `image file`and it takes approx 0,8 MB of memory increase. How to avoid this?

```
private ImageView mImageName;

private void update(){
mImageName.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/" + mQuestionLibrary.getImage(mQuestionNumber), null, getPackageName()));
}
```

Comment: Do you have a number of imageviews or just one?

Comment: @Xenolion just one

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Image Resource Importer to have multiple sizes for different screens.

Then you need to set your Image by this code:

```
mImageName.setImageResource(R.drawable.resource_name);
```

[image]

you can also moodify the `mQuestionLibrary.getImage(mQuestionNumber)` to return the resource id instead of resource name, and then use:

```
mImageName.setImageResource(mQuestionLibrary.getImage(mQuestionNumber));
```

Comment: Do you think will reduce the memory? How? For me it looks like an alternative only!??

Comment: As my experiment, it will. I had a crash of OutOfMemory Error, and this was my solution.

Comment: Okay got yeah then!

Comment: @Januszj. This was a solution of a crash caused by OutOfMemory Error. And my solution fixed the crash.

Comment: @Khalid Taha Did u store res ID or only names?

Comment: @Januszj. I stored the IDs only, no need for the name.

Comment: your problem is NOT in the resource name, but it is because you are using one image with static size, you have to use the ResourceImporter plugin in android studio to import multiple images with different screen sizes and your issue will be fixed

Comment: @KhalidTaha I dont use one image, I use multiple images. I change them by calling method update().

Comment: @Januszj. in your question comments, you mentioned that you use one image, BTW, I meant you should support different screen sizes by using multiple images for every resource: ldpi, hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi

Comment: @KhalidTaha I do it but I didnt mention it. One drawable used size is approx 100 kB but memory comes to 0,8 MB for this method.

Comment: @Januszj. Just try my solution and your issue will be fixed, I'm sure!

Comment: @KhalidTaha There is no any difference in memory if I call mImageName.setImageResource(R.drawable.tab1); or  mImageName.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/" + mQuestionLibrary.getImage(mQuestionNumber), null, getPackageName())); for same res ID. The problem should be within setImageResource method and memory managment in this method.

Comment: @Januszj. As I told you, the problem is NOT in the call, the problem is in your file. use Image Resource Importer to generate 6 files for multiple screens and forget the resource ID.

Comment: @KhalidTaha I got 5 files for each drawable. I dont use drawable/nodpi as device use mdpi and there is the file. No matter.

Comment: @Januszj. Use the plugin the the updated answer, I added an Image

Comment: @KhalidTaha I found the solution.

Comment: What was your solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The problem was that I have had setted in `ImageView` layout properties: `adjustViewBounds` and unneccesarry `src`. Those properties takes a lot of memory.

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iV_pytanie"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/tab1"
                />
```

I deleted them and memory decreased by approx 0,5 MB for each image.

Comment: adjustViewBounds will not take memory, only the src may take.